# Making child element unresponsive to parent element's onclick-function, but responsive to its own contents

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have list elements with onclick-functions that will change the display of each list element and its child div, and move them to the top of the list. By clicking on the list element again everything reverses.

The problem is, that the child div contains search fields for input, clickable pictures and perhaps text that the user might want to copy. Clicking on any of these will simply reverse the list element.

JS

```js
function showCombo(x) {
  x.classList.toggle('active')
}
```

CSS

```css
li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 2px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li div {
   display: none;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
}

li.active {
   width: 100%; /* full width */
   order: -1; /* move to the top */
}

li.active div {
   display: block; /* show div */
}
```

HTML

```html
<ul>
 <li onclick="showCombo(this)">
    <p>Title 1</p>
    <div>Show content</div>
 </li>
 <li onclick="showCombo(this)">
   <p>Title 2</p>
   <div>Show content</div>
 </li>
 <li onclick="showCombo(this)">
   <p>Title 3</p>
   <div>Show content</div>
 </li>
  <li onclick="showCombo(this)">
   <p>Title 4</p>
   <div>Show content</div>
 </li>
 <li onclick="showCombo(this)">
   <p>Title 5</p>
   <div>Show content</div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Is there any way to make the child div unclickable while keeping the parent li clickable, and at the same time allowing the content of the child div to be used?

pointer-events:none; simply disables everything inside the div. No links can be clicked or input into search field be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function showCombo(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.target.classList.toggle('active')
}
```

```css
li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 2px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li div {
  display: none;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
}

li.active {
  width: 100%;
  /* full width */
  order: -1;
  /* move to the top */
}

li.active div {
  display: block;
  /* show div */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li onclick="showCombo(event)">
    <p>Title 1</p>
    <div >Show content</div>
  </li>
  <li onclick="showCombo(event)">
    <p>Title 2</p>
    <div>Show content</div>
  </li>
  <li onclick="showCombo(event)">
    <p>Title 3</p>
    <div>Show content</div>
  </li>
  <li onclick="showCombo(event)">
    <p>Title 4</p>
    <div>Show content</div>
  </li>
  <li onclick="showCombo(event)">
    <p>Title 5</p>
    <div>Show content</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
click(function(e) { 
e. stopPropagation(); 
});
```

Bind this event on parent click function to stop propogation on child elements.